# How to position an <hr> line 3 pixels under text

Tags: html, css, line, css-position

So, in my website, I have some text at the front. I'm trying to put a `<hr>` 3 pixels under the text, however even when I try to dynamically position it, the `<hr>` still stays in the same place. Even try positioning it in this JSFiddle:

[Text on top of HR line 3px](https://jsfiddle.net/GamerMatt/s081w4vp/)

As you could probably tell, I cannot position it... and at the moment, it kind of looks ugly.

In the full website that I made, I have a `<video>` html tag, which is playing. It also has a top menu so that you can choose what category of my website you want to choose. Here's a screenshot:

[image: My website]

I'm also planning to add a button directly under the `<hr>`, but I think I should stick to this problem first.

Comment: can you add a snapshot of how exactly you want the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the `<hr>` and try adding the line to the paragraph.

Like this:

```
#toptext p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    line-height: 66px;
}
```

Then adjust the line-height.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that you could add underlined text, but I never knew that there was a feature to position the underline. :D

Comment: Cool, but avoid to use line-height in px, use like line-height:1.3;

Answer (score 3):

What happens in your current code is that the browser defaults are `p {margin: ...some value depending on browser...;}`.

So you must first add your own CSS rule to overwrite it, here: `#toptext p {margin: 0;}`.

Then you can freely choose how to position your `<hr>` using its `margin-top`.
Note that, as you have a big font-size for the text, it keeps some space under it, so you may have to use a *negative* margin for `<hr>`, like in the example below:

```css
#toptext {
 font-family:"Open Sans", san-serif, Arial;
 font-size:500%;
 color:#000;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 top:5px;
 text-align:center;
 left:15%;
}
#toptext p {
  margin: 0;
}
#line {
 height: .5px;
 background-color: #03f;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="toptext">
  <p>MatthewTheBottleFlipper</p>
  <hr id="line"/>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove all the excess css overkill and [lets keep life simple :)](https://jsfiddle.net/s081w4vp/2/)

**HTML**

```
  <p>MatthewTheBottleFlipper</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    font-family:"Open Sans", san-serif, Arial;
    font-size:500%;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    text-align:center;
    left:15%;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #000; /* u need this */
    padding-bottom:3px /* ...and this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The p tag naturally has margins and padding. Just remove it, and everything will work how you want:

```
#toptext {
font-family:"Open Sans", san-serif, Arial;
font-size:500%;
color:#000;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
top:5px;
text-align:center;
left:15%;
}

#line {
height:0.5px;
background-color:#03f;
margin-top: 3px /* I can't position this three pixels under text */
}

p { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```